# How to dynamically inject <authentication> into azure-webapp-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, azure, maven, web-applications

By default, the Azure deploy maven command should use an auto-login authentication (URL with login code) on local developer machines. But, the CI server will inject additional service principal parameters for login.

Given the "pom.xml" configuration...

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${azure-webapp-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <schemaVersion>${azure-webapp-maven-plugin.schema.version}</schemaVersion>
          <allowTelemetry>false</allowTelemetry>
          <subscriptionId>${azure.subscription.id}</subscriptionId>
          <resourceGroup>${azure.resourcegroup}</resourceGroup>
          <appName>${azure.appservice.name}</appName>
          <appServicePlanName>${azure.appservice.plan.name}</appServicePlanName>
          <pricingTier>${azure.appservice.plan.pricingtier}</pricingTier>
          <region>${azure.region}</region>
          <runtime>
            <os>${azure.appservice.plan.os}</os>
            <javaVersion>${azure.java.version}</javaVersion>
            <webContainer>${azure.java.version}</webContainer>
          </runtime>
          <appSettings>
            <property>
              <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
              <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
            </property>
          </appSettings>
          <deployment>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>*.jar</include>
                </includes>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </deployment>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

... I want to dynamically specify to use `<authentication>` parameters specified in the "settings.xml" file defined as ...

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <properties>
        <azure.tenant.id>
          <!--
            Set the Azure subscription identifier via command line:
            ./mvnw -s ./ci-settings.xml ... "-Dazure.tenant.id=enter-value-here"
          -->
        </azure.tenant.id>
        <azure.client.id>
          <!--
            Set the Azure service principal identifier via command line:
            ./mvnw -s ./ci-settings.xml ... "-Dazure.client.id=enter-value-here"
          -->
        </azure.client.id>
        <azure.client.key>
          <!--
            Set the Azure service principal password via command line:
            ./mvnw -s ./ci-settings.xml ... "-Dazure.client.key=enter-value-here"
          -->
        </azure.client.key>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>azure-auth</id>
      <configuration>
        <tenant>${azure.tenant.id}</tenant>
        <client>${azure.client.id}</client>
        <key>${azure.client.key}</key>
        <environment>AZURE</environment>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

... but, can't figure out how to tell the plug-in NOT to use `auto` login detection with a URL prompt and login code, but to instead use the service principal credentials specified in "settings.xml" by executing a command like:

```
        ./mvnw -B -s ./settings.xml \
            clean package azure-webapp:deploy \
            "-Dazure.tenant.id=$(tenant-id)" \
            "-Dazure.client.id=$(client-id)" \
            "-Dazure.client.key=$(client-key)" \
            "-Dazure.subscription.id=$(subscription-id)" \
            "-Dazure.resourcegroup=$(resource-group)" \
            "-Dazure.region=$(region)" \
            "-Dazure.appservice.name=$(appservice-name)" \
            "-Dazure.appservice.plan.name=$(appservice-plan-name)" \
            "-Dazure.appservice.plan.os=$(appservice-plan-os)" \
            "-Dazure.appservice.plan.pricingtier=$(appservice-plan-tier)"
```

I've attempted to define the `<serverId>` as a plugin parameter on the command-line, but can't figure out what the path is to set it dynamically (e.g. `-Dwebapp.authentication.serverId=azure-auth` still results in a URL prompt for a login code instead of using the service principal credentials).

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around using  to override the configuration, but would prefer dynamic configuration via maven command parameters.

**"pom.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-boot</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <azure-maven-plugin.version>0.2.0</azure-maven-plugin.version>
    <azure-webapp-maven-plugin.version>1.8.0</azure-webapp-maven-plugin.version>
    <azure-webapp-maven-plugin.schema.version>V2</azure-webapp-maven-plugin.schema.version>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <azure.java.version>java11</azure.java.version>
    <azure.client.id>
      <!--
        For CI, Set the Azure service principal identifier via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.client.id=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.client.id>
    <azure.client.key>
      <!--
        For CI, Set the Azure service principal password via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.client.key=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.client.key>
    <azure.tenant.id>
      <!--
        For CI, Set the Azure tenant identifier via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.tenant.id=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.tenant.id>
    <azure.subscription.id>
      <!--
        Set the Azure subscription identifier via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.subscription.id=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.subscription.id>
    <azure.resourcegroup>
      <!--
        Set the Azure resource group via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.resourcegroup=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.resourcegroup>
    <azure.region>
      eastus
      <!--
        Override the Azure region via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.region=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.region>
    <azure.appservice.name>
      <!--
        Set the Azure App Service name via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.appservice.name=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.appservice.name>
    <azure.appservice.plan.name>
      <!--
        Set the Azure App Service plan name via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.appservice.plan.name=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.appservice.plan.name>
    <azure.appservice.plan.os>
      linux
      <!--
        Override the Azure App Service plan name via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.appservice.plan.os=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.appservice.plan.os>
    <azure.appservice.plan.pricingtier>
      B1
      <!--
        Override the Azure App Service plan name via command line:
        ./mvnw ... "-Dazure.appservice.plan.pricingtier=enter-value-here"
      -->
    </azure.appservice.plan.pricingtier>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end::actuator[] -->
    <!-- tag::tests[] -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end::tests[] -->
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${azure-webapp-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <schemaVersion>${azure-webapp-maven-plugin.schema.version}</schemaVersion>
          <allowTelemetry>false</allowTelemetry>
          <subscriptionId>${azure.subscription.id}</subscriptionId>
          <resourceGroup>${azure.resourcegroup}</resourceGroup>
          <appName>${azure.appservice.name}</appName>
          <appServicePlanName>${azure.appservice.plan.name}</appServicePlanName>
          <pricingTier>${azure.appservice.plan.pricingtier}</pricingTier>
          <region>${azure.region}</region>
          <runtime>
            <os>${azure.appservice.plan.os}</os>
            <javaVersion>${azure.java.version}</javaVersion>
            <webContainer>${azure.java.version}</webContainer>
          </runtime>
          <appSettings>
            <property>
              <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
              <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
            </property>
          </appSettings>
          <deployment>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>*.jar</include>
                </includes>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </deployment>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>deploy-ci</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>azure.client.id</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-webapp-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <auth>
                <tenant>${azure.tenant.id}</tenant>
                <client>${azure.client.id}</client>
                <key>${azure.client.key}</key>
                <environment>AZURE</environment>
              </auth>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

The above can then be configured and run using optional parameters that contain a service principal login credentials.

**"Makefile"**

```
deploy:
ifdef CI
    @./mvnw azure-webapp:deploy \
        "-Dazure.tenant.id=$(tenant-id)" \
        "-Dazure.client.id=$(client-id)" \
        "-Dazure.client.key=$(client-key)" \
        "-Dazure.subscription.id=$(subscription-id)" \
        "-Dazure.resourcegroup=$(resource-group)" \
        "-Dazure.region=$(region)" \
        "-Dazure.appservice.name=$(appservice-name)" \
        "-Dazure.appservice.plan.name=$(appservice-plan-name)" \
        "-Dazure.appservice.plan.os=$(appservice-plan-os)" \
        "-Dazure.appservice.plan.pricingtier=$(appservice-plan-tier)"
else
    @./mvnw azure-webapp:deploy \
        "-Dazure.subscription.id=$(subscription-id)" \
        "-Dazure.resourcegroup=$(resource-group)" \
        "-Dazure.region=$(region)" \
        "-Dazure.appservice.name=$(appservice-name)" \
        "-Dazure.appservice.plan.name=$(appservice-plan-name)" \
        "-Dazure.appservice.plan.os=$(appservice-plan-os)" \
        "-Dazure.appservice.plan.pricingtier=$(appservice-plan-tier)"
endif
```